# The browser shows 404 Not Found when I'm using a RewriteRule on the server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I had to reinstall the whole Ubuntu 14 to 16.04.3 to be able to upgrade PHP to 7.0. Now there is Ubuntu 16 on the machine, but my website is broken. It was using Apache and mod_rewrite.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
...
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName api.example.com
        ServerAdmin janos@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/api.example.com
        <Directory "/var/www/api.example.com">
                Options -Indexes
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api.example.com.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api.example.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
...
```

On the server:

```
janos@example:/var/www/api.example.com$ ls -l .htaccess dir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 janos janos   65 okt   31 09:10 .htaccess

dir:
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 janos janos 6 okt   31 09:09 hello.txt
janos@example:/var/www/api.example.com$ cat .htaccess 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    "^test.txt$"     "dir/hello.txt"
janos@example:/var/www/api.example.com$ sudo service apache2 restart
janos@example:/var/www/api.example.com$ sudo a2enmod rewrite 
Module rewrite already enabled
```

On my client:

```
mymachine:Downloads janos$ curl -Is  http://api.example.com/test.txt|grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
mymachine:Downloads janos$ curl -Is  http://api.example.com/dir|grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
mymachine:Downloads janos$ curl -Is  http://api.example.com/dir/|grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
mymachine:Downloads janos$ curl -Is  http://api.example.com/dir/hello.txt|grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
mymachine:Downloads janos$
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `janos@example:/var/www/example.hej.hu$ php -i|grep rewrite`  
_url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was:  I didn't allowed user defined htaccess files to change the mod_rewrite and other rules. The correct config part is:

```
    <Directory "/var/www/api.example.com">
            Options -Indexes
    # it's working now with this following 1 line added:
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
```